# Terraform unable to create role and assign it for AWS spot fleet resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When launching spot fleet using terraform example [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_fleet_request.html) I need to provide the required value.

```
iam_fleet_role      = "arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/spot-fleet"
```

However, I do not want to provide the account number so I want to create a role and attach the "AmazonEC2SpotFleetTaggingRole" policy so I wrote the code below, but I'm getting the error:

```
* aws_spot_fleet_request.cheap_compute: "iam_fleet_role" doesn't look like a valid ARN ("^arn:[\\w-]+:([a-zA-Z0-9\\-])+:([a-z]{2}-(gov-)?[a-z]+-\\d{1})?:(\\d{12})?:(.*)$"): "test_role"
```

What am I doing wrong or should I be doing it some other way?

```
 resource "aws_iam_role" "test_role" {
      name = "test_role"

      assume_role_policy = <<EOF
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Sid": ""
        }
      ]
    }
    EOF
    }
    resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEC2SpotFleetTaggingRole-policy-attachment" {
        role = "${aws_iam_role.test_role.name}"
        policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2SpotFleetTaggingRole"
    }


# Request a Spot fleet
resource "a`enter code here`ws_spot_fleet_request" "cheap_compute" {
  iam_fleet_role      = "${aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEC2SpotFleetTaggingRole-policy-attachment.role}"
  spot_price          = "0.77"
  allocation_strategy = "diversified"
  target_capacity     = 2
  valid_until         = "2018-06-11T20:44:20Z"

  launch_specification {
    instance_type     = "t2.micro"
    ami               = "ami-1853ac65"
    spot_price        = "0.777"
    availability_zone = "us-east-1a"

    tags {
    Name = "spot-fleet-example"
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple issues here:

- [Spot Fleet role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/spot_fleet_IAM_role.html) require that you have a trust relationship set for `spotfleet.amazonaws.com`
- You are referencing the created role incorrectly, you need to reference the `arn` attribute of your `aws_iam_role` resource

### Example

#### Create your Spot Fleet role as referenced above:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "example" {
  name = "example-fleet-role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "spotfleet.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

#### Attach the AWS managed policy to the role

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEC2SpotFleetTaggingRole-policy-attachment" {
  role = "${aws_iam_role.example.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2SpotFleetTaggingRole"
}
```

#### Use the role with a spot fleet request by using the `arn` attribute from `aws_iam_role`

```
resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "cheap_compute" {
  iam_fleet_role      = "${aws_iam_role.example.arn}"
  spot_price          = "0.77"
  allocation_strategy = "diversified"
  target_capacity     = 2
  valid_until         = "2018-06-11T20:44:20Z"

  launch_specification {
    instance_type     = "t2.micro"
    ami               = "ami-1853ac65"
    spot_price        = "0.777"
    availability_zone = "us-east-1a"

    tags {
    Name = "spot-fleet-example"
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: thank you, I discovered your method and I was able to make it work.

Comment: Is there a typo in the resource aws_iam_role? In my case is not `policy` but `assume_role_policy`

Comment: Fixed @Arcones. Thanks.